# AdColony UI is messed up on Galaxy S6 (using Unity 5 & HeyZap)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, ads, adcolony, heyzap

I have a game that I'm making for Android using Unity 5.3.5p2 (64 bit) and Heyzap Mediation v9.5.7. I implemented AdColony v2.1.4 using HeyZap and it works fine on my Samsung Galaxy Avant, but on my Samsung Galaxy S6 the time left circle and the x button are misaligned during the ad and on the ad end screen, but they only work if you touch where they're supposed to be. Any idea why or how to fix it? I have implemented it correctly and all the other ad networks and SDKs I have work fine (Branch.io, GameAnalytics, HeyZap, Applovin, Chartboost, and UnityAds (although I had this bug before I added UnityAds). Here are some screenshots of the bug:

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: You use all the ad network sdk/plugin in the-same app?

Comment: lol why are you even doing that?  why not use just one ad sdk?

Comment: @Programmer look up ad mediation, that's what I'm using its pretty self explanatory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed Adcolony about it, and they said it only happens on Galaxy S6s running android 6.0 not 5.0 or 5.1. They said they think they have a fix and will release it soon.